# st_contains not matching point in linestring

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have data that contains linestring geometries.

```
select st_astext(fullpath) from t limit 1;
-----------------------------------------------------------
LINESTRING(-117.9394066 33.7621968,-117.9394143 33.7618166)
```

If I try to select this record by one of the points in the line, it doesn't match.

```
select * from t where st_contains(fullpath, st_makepoint(33.7618166,-117.9394143));
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 records found
```

Reading the doc for this function, I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Flip around lat & lon in *st_makepoint* call.

Comment: Tried that & also got nothing.

Comment: It is tough to compare real numbers. Consider *ST_DWithin* instead `select ST_DWithin(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-117.9394066 33.7621968,-117.9394143 33.7618166)'), st_makepoint(-117.9394143, 33.7618166), .01);`

Comment: @mlt Don't answer in comments, make a proper answer so that the OP can accept it.

Comment: @Patrick My personal take on that is that Q is not valuable for community but I don't mind to resolve OP's issue. Also there is a [GIS@SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) where PostGIS questions are more likely will find answers. I'd delete this Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ST_Covers`.

Here's an example modified from @mlt's comment:

```
test=# select ST_Covers(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-117.9394066 33.7621968,-117.9394143 33.7618166)'), st_makepoint(-117.9394066, 33.7621968));
 st_covers 
-----------
 t
(1 row)
```